# Are there any type of representation on filesystem for network ports?

Tags: filesystems, network-interface

Say I wish to feed some data into a certain network port created on my system and do that manually.  Is there any interface for it on filesystem?
Maybe a special type of file that I could write into? If not how does it all work?

(I am asking this question despite the risk of sounding ridiculous and not making sense at all. I'd gladly accept link to some good article on the topic.)

Comment: You can use `netcat`: `echo foo | nc host ip`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In short

You cannot do what you describe in a way such as using `cat` to write to a file and have it send out over the network. However there are tools that can do this. I'd recommend looking into either `netcat` or `socat` (socat is more flexible, but slightly more confusing). Either will likely be in your distributions repos.

## Explanation

In Linux, IP sockets exist in userspace and do not have a file in the filesystem per se.

To demonstrate this I ran `$ lsof -i :15115` (port 15115 is associated with Skype):

```
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
skype   3836 eightbit   43u  IPv4 9020794      0t0  TCP *:15115 (LISTEN)
skype   3836 eightbit   44u  IPv4 9020795      0t0  UDP *:15115
```

So process `3836` has a file descriptor numbered `43` for the TCP socket `15115` (the 'u' just means the file is open with r+w permissions).

So if I do `$ ls -l /proc/3836/fd/43 && file /proc/3836/fd/43` I get:

```
lrwx------ 1 eightbit eightbit 64 Sep 26 00:37 /proc/3836/fd/43 -> socket:[9020794]
/proc/3836/fd/43: broken symbolic link to socket:[9020794]
```

As you can see the socket is not *really* a file.